# AppSync GraphQL query with nextToken

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

My `schema.graphql` file auto generated below query in `graphql/queries.js` file by running `amplify push` command.

Here is the schema file that generates query automatically.

**schema.graphql**

```
type User @model {
  id: String!
  uuid: String!
  following: [String]
  follower: [String]
  posts: [Post] @connection(name: "Userposts", sortField: "createdAt")
}

type Post 
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner },
      { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  author: User! @connection(name: "Userposts")
  status: Status!
  draft: Boolean
  content: AWSJSON!
  loved: [String]
  comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "PostComments", sortField: "createdAt")
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
    updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}

enum Status {
  PRIVATE
  PUBLIC
}
```

Here's the queries generated by schema graphql.

**queries.js**

```
export const getUser = `query GetUser($id: ID!) {
  getUser(id: $id) {
    id
    uuid
    following
    follower
    posts(limit: 10, sortDirection: DESC) {
      items {
        id
        privacy
        draft
        content
        loved
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
    notifications {
      items {
        id
        content
        category
        link
        createdAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
}
`;
```

I added `(limit: 10, sortDirection: DESC)` to `posts` to get the 10 latest posts from the user but can't figure out how to pass `nextToken` value to get another 10 posts after the first query.

How do I pass `nextToken` value to the posts so I can get next 10 posts?

Comment: do you mind also sharing your schema.graphql?

Comment: Added the schema!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using the `graphqlOperation` helper method:

```
const newData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listUser, { nextToken }));
```

Here, `nextToken` from previous request is passed as an argument using [object shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

Comment: Yes, but I 'm using `const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getUser, {id: username}))` to get all user data which include journals with nextToken. I want to know if it's possible to call another `const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getUser, {id: username}))` with nextToken.

Comment: @Ohsik The short answer is yes you can call more queries with `nextToken` it will automatically be `null` if there is nothing more to query. If that doesn't answer your question, please try to elaborate more and I might help you.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. How do I call `getUser` with `nextToken` since it only takes `id` as a parameter(`getUser(id: $id)`). There are more than 10 posts to query and it should not be `null`. Please let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: I think I got it. If you used AWS Amplify to generate your queries, you will have a file located at (in React) `src/graphql/queries.js`. In it you will find `getUser` as well as `listUsers`. `getUser` (or `get` queries in general) are for getting **single** instances. `list` are for getting multiple. In `listUsers` you should see that it takes three argements: `$filter: ModelUserFilterInput`, `$limit: Int` and `$nextToken: String`. That's what you are looking for. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you got it! so I just can't use `getUser` to get next 10 posts. I have to use `listUers`. I was hoping there are ways to use `getUser` :(

Comment: @Ohsik Why? What feature does `getUser` have that `listUser` doesn't?

Comment: For my use case, ‘getUser’ gets me 10 posts from that specific user and I can use ‘sortDirection’ to get latest 10 posts. However, ‘listPost’ doesn’t take user and sort direction parameter which makes it harder to get 10 latest posts from by user id.

Comment: @Ohsik, yes it can. You can use its `filter` parameter to get the user's posts along with `limit` to get more than 10 posts. And you might need to use local secondary indexes.

Comment: @J.Hesters if you want to get all posts from a user, you have to use getUser, because listPosts won't have a filter for the user, or is there? To my understanding the filter input won't contain any id for the connection

Answer (score 3):

not sure if you're still working on this or what your solution may have ended up being, but I think the following should work as well:

as part of the amplify codegen process, it should create a folder called "graphql", where it will place a schema.json, subscriptons.graphql, queries.graphql, and mutations.graphql. In this folder, you can add a custom file called anything you want. I usually call mine customqueries.graphql. and it will pick up these queries or mutations or whatever you define in the codegen process. So in that file you could define a GetUserPostsCustom query that takes in the nextToken for the posts, like so:

```
query GetUserPostsCustom($id: ID!, $nextToken: String) {
  getUser(id: $id) {
    posts(nextToken: $nextToken){
      items{
        id
        title
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
}
```

and then when you call your api if you call the GetUserPostsCustom, there should be an option to pass in the nextToken. At least I believe this works when generating code for swift. not sure about javascript.